# Add fields in custom taxonomy in WordPress admin for saved data

Tags: wordpress, field, custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I want to add custom fields in custom taxonomy for my plugin in form-fields and also show saved data as like name, slug and description are showed.
Someone suggest something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function custom_column_header( $columns ){
  $columns['address'] = 'Address'; 
  $columns['phoneno'] = 'Phone No';

  return $columns;
}

add_filter( "manage_edit-nwcm_news_category_columns", 'custom_column_header', 10);
```

// To show the column value

```
function custom_column_content( $value, $column_name , $term){

    if ($column_name === 'address') {
        $t_id = $term;
        $term_meta = get_option( "$t_id" ); 
        print_r($term_meta['address']);
    }
    if ($column_name === 'phoneno') {
        $t_id = $term;
        $term_meta = get_option( "$t_id" ); 
        print_r($term_meta['phone']);
    }

}
add_action( "manage_nwcm_news_category_custom_column", 'custom_column_content', 10, 3);
```

Comment: hope this link also helps https://codingrhymes.in/blog/add-custom-meta-fields-to-taxonomies/